# create table in sql server specific to sql database

Tags: php, sql-server, database, odbc

I have 2 databases which work together to monitor the doors being opened. The structure of the databases is similar to the below:

**Database 1- Events Table:**

- EventId (Autonumber)
- EventDateTime (Date and time)
- DoorId (int)
- Person (int) - Stores the PersonId

**Database 2 - Persons table:**

- PersonId (Autonumber)
- Person FirstName
- PersonLastName

Using php I need help to return the following information:

- EventDateTime (from Events table in Database 1).
- Person Name (From Persons table in Database 2).

Is it possible to return data from 2 seperate (but related) databases?

Comment: are you having a specific issue? This is an overly broad question. The short answer is yes, write a stored procedure that pulls from both DB's and return that.

Comment: I am sorry but this looks more like a **specification** than a question.

Comment: You can use 3 part naming to reference objects in another database on the same server. [DatabaseName].schema.objectname. It is no big deal, you can use joins and reference it just like any other object.

Comment: @SeanLange thats assuming they are on the same instance/machine, OP may need linked servers and 4 part names. Seems like not, but you never know.

Comment: @DanielE. that is why I said "on the same server". :D Was hoping we would hear something from the OP indicating if that was the case or not.